# Assembly coding strdup. Malloc calling in shared library

Tags: assembly, shared-libraries, nasm, x86-64

I have a problem, I can't compile my strdup while calling malloc.
When I don't call malloc, it compiles my shared library perfectly, so if someone could help me that would be great !

here is my code:

---

```
BITS 64
DEFAULT REL
        global my_strdup:function
        extern malloc
my_strdup:

[...]

    call malloc
```

---

I compile with this:

$> nasm -f elf64 my_strdup.S

$> gcc -shared -o libmy.so my_strdup.o

/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: my_strdup.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have this error. I don't understand it ! I have a 64bit computer. 
It is the first time I try Assembly.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a shared library that calls function from another shared library might not be the best thing for a first assembly program ;)

That said, here is what the [nasm manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.3) has to say about this:

> Referring to a procedure name using wrt ..plt causes the linker to
>   build a procedure linkage table entry for the symbol, and the
>   reference gives the address of the PLT entry. You can only use this in
>   contexts which would generate a PC-relative relocation normally (i.e.
>   as the destination for CALL or JMP), since ELF contains no relocation
>   type to refer to PLT entries absolutely.

So, what you need is `call malloc wrt ..plt`.